# Display web page according to html string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have HTML script string stored in database. I am fetching this string in one variable.

I want to display page out of this html string below `gethtml` button in below .aspx page.

[image]

I searched how to display sub html page inside main aspx page.

I came to know with `webbrowser` control, but not finding it anywhere in tool box.

Is there any other control or way to show html page out of html script in above main aspx page?

Please help me.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about html source. It is a full web page or just html code? if it is the full page you can use iframe to display, in case it is the html code you can use javascript to "insert" that html source to a container like a `div` by using `document.getElementById('yourdivid').innerHTML = 'your html source';`

Comment: html source string can be just : <html><body><input type="text" id="txtName"/></body></html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="htmlpage" runat="server"></div>
```

in code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ss="<h1>Hello world</h1>";//your html string
        htmlpage.InnerHtml = ss;
    }
```